# How to pass variables when using multiple module exports which are dependent on the result of another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have three files: user.js, influencer.js, & validate.js

In user.js, I import ./influencer (as var = influencer) & ./validate (as var = validate).

My function in user.js:

```
addAccount: function(){
 return functions.database.ref('/acct/{accountID}/name/').onCreate(event => {
  var accountID = event.params.accountID;
  var name = JSON.stringify(event.data.val()).replace(/['"]+/g, '');

  console.log("New Account Added ("+accountID+")");
  console.log("Nickname: " +name);

  influencer.getIG(name);

  var data = influencer.data;

  validate.validateThis(data);
 });
}
```

With influencer.getIG(name), I am passing the name we defined above to the function getIG (inside of influencer.js). This works like a charm. The result is JSON body.

What I want to do now is take this JSON body result and pass it to the validate function (in validate.js). In influencer.js, I also added "exports.data = data;".

With that being said, I can't seem to figure out how to pass "data" to validate.js. I log it, and it returns undefined. I added a timeout before running validateThis(data) and still undefined. The validate function on its own works great; I've tested it. But clearly, I am not doing this the correct way.

This is my influencer.getIG function:

```
module.exports = {
 getIG: function (name) {
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+name+"/?__a=1"

  console.log(url);

  request({
    url: url
  }, function (error, response, body) {

   var data = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log(data);
   exports.data = data;
  })
 }
}
```

How can I pass the result of the second module to the third module in my function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like `influencer.getIG()` is asynchronous, which means you need a callback or a promise to know when it's finished before you can access `influencer.data`. Can you edit your question to include code for `influencer.getIG`?

Comment: is influencer.getIG(name) asynchronous? if it is, then data = influencer.data may be called before the actual data is retrieved. You may have to use callback or promise if that's the case.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question with those details. I did add a big timeout, however, to ensure that influencer.getIG() would be finished before letting validateThis(data) run. It still returned undefined, though.

Comment: The reason is you cannot declare an export variable from inside the callback.  
When you call require, javascript executes that piece of code from top to bottom.  when you call var influencer = require('influencer), it will execute the code within the influencer.js and return everything in it when it hits the end the first time. It won't wait for the callback to result.  So anything defined within a callback will always be null.  Adding timeouts won't help. It's not a race condition. It's because you can't set the variables inside the callbacks.

Comment: @EugeneG that actually makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing callback function as another parameter to getIG

Your influencer file will look like this.

```
module.exports = {
  getIG: function (name, callback) {
    var url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+name+"/?__a=1"

    request({
      url: url
    }, callback)
  }
}
```

And your user file will look like this

```
addAccount: function(){
  return functions.database.ref('/acct/{accountID}/name/').onCreate(event => {
    var accountID = event.params.accountID;
    var name = JSON.stringify(event.data.val()).replace(/['"]+/g, '');

    influencer.getIG(name, function (error, response, body) {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      validate.validateThis(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Using callback will ensure that data is retrieved before you call it.

Comment: This was perfect. I'm not quite sure why this works the way it does exactly (I'm new to callbacks), but it's amazing. You have an extra closing parenthesis on the third to last line of addAccount, but otherwise, it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @ryangineer I will try to explain it the best I can. First of all, from your code when you getIG without a callback, javascript will immediately run the next command which is var data = influencer.data; because javascript doesn't wait for asynchronous operation like http get to finish. At that time the data hasn't arrived and you get undefined. However a callback will be called after an asynchronous operation has finished and data has arrived so you are guaranteed to received the data (if any).

Answer (score 1):

As the two other commentors noted - you have an asynchronous function with a callback.  One way around this is to define the callback inside the user.js file, and pass it to the getIG function.  So you would have

## user.js

```
<pre><code>
addAccount: function(){
return functions.database.ref('/acct/{accountID}/name/').onCreate(event => {
var accountID = event.params.accountID;
var name = JSON.stringify(event.data.val()).replace(/['"]+/g, '');

console.log("New Account Added ("+accountID+")");
console.log("Nickname: " +name);

function callback(err, res, data) {
var data = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(data);
validate.validateThis(data)
}      

influencer.getIG(name, callback);
});
}
</pre></code>
```

then in the other file

## influencer.js

```
module.exports = {
getIG: function (name, callback) {
var url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+name+"/?__a=1"
request({
url: url
}, callback)
}
}
```

This way the asynchronous function runs inside of influencer, and then calls back to the user when the result is done. Data is now in scope for the user file to utilize.

The alternative (and better) way is to use promises.  In that case the user code would be along the lines of

influencer.getIg(name).then(data => //use data here in user.js//)